# Обновить страницу javascript

Tags: javascript

Внутри формы находится таблица.
Внутри таблицы кнопки открывающие всплювающие окна.
Там при помощи `Javascript` я отправляю `POST,GET` запросы. После чего хочу перезагрузить страницу что бы она отобразила своё новое состояние (таблицы), но проблема в том, что после изменения полей, он каждый раз при вызове "`location.reload`" выдает предупреждение, что данные изменились и просит подтверждения.
Есть ли способы при помощи Javascript принудительно обновить страницу?
Я бы сделал кнопку запуска Javascript'ника `submit`, но т.к. он находится внутри другой формы, то работать будет не корректно.

Может быть можно создать другие поля? Не input, на которые не будет реагировать защита сохранения данных

Comment: Почему не перезагружать состояние таблицы без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Слишком много всего происходит там

Comment: `window.location = window.location.href` - так он не обновит страницу с запросом, а перейдет по своему же урлу с пустым запросом.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
  document.forms.my.reset(); // сбрасываем форму
  location.reload(); // перезагружаем страницу
}
```

```html
<form name="my" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="123">
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Сбросить средствами html">
</form>
<button id="reset">сбросить и перезагрузить средствами  js</button>
```

Comment: нет, так он все равно будет слать данные, ничего не изменится, в таком варианте если только форму сабмитить.

Comment: нарисовывается тогда, по логике. проверка на сервере, заполнения полей формы и если не заполнены определенные то не обрабатывать

Comment: при таком обновлении на сервер уйдет предыдущий запрос, так что не получится

Answer (score 0):

Просто измени window.location c помощью JS. Это не безопасно т.к если юзер нажмет назад то форма отправится повторно 
Рекомендуется использовать паттерн [POST/REDIRECT/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) 
[Ссылка на похожий вопрос с англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript)

Comment: window.location = window.location.href; не помогает, все равно спрашивает хочу ли я покинуть страницу и потерять данные

Comment: @РусланРуслан Другие советы с ссылки то же помогли?

Comment: Да, единственная идея была сделать скрытый submit но т.к. это внутри формы то работать не будет

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй перенаправить страницу на неё же саму location.href=' '

Если же нет то можно перенаправить страницу по новому GET параметру который ничего не будет отправлять

Comment: Неа, никакие манипуляции с location не работают

Comment: @Harron каким образом перенаправить, если предупреждение выскакивает для формы с post запросом, если вызывать другую форму, то всё равно будет запрос кидать о возможной потере данных